# OnKeydown first character is not captured

Tags: jquery

I want to capture an event data from the textbox but it returns empty for the text entered. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here? The name is not alerted for the first character entered. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#name").keydown(function(event){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                alert("name" + name);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="name">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use 'keyup' event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#name").keyup(function() {
var dInput = $(this).val();
alert(dInput);
     });});
```

Try the above Code . or see Demo :[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/LXQxy/)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting value of textbox even before it has been set. You should try to get the value from event arguments. You can get the press key with event.keycode as follows

```
$(function() {
      $("#name").keydown(function(event){
            // Just to make sure it works in all browsers
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            var userInput = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
             alert("name"+userInput );
      });
  });
```